# Typing a mapShape function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I want to use a utility function like this:

```
const out = mapShape(
  { foo: 1, bar: '2', baz: 'hello' },
  { foo: x => String(x), bar: x => parseInt(x) }
)
// outputs { foo: '1', bar: 2 }
```

Is there a way to parameterize it in TypeScript so that the type of the output will be this?

```
{ foo: string, bar: number }
```

I tried doing this:

```
export default function mapShape<
  I extends Record<any, any>,
  X extends { [K in keyof I]: (value: I[K], key: K, object: I) => any }
>(
  object: I,
  mapper: Partial<X>
): {
  [K in keyof I]: ReturnType<X[K]>
} {
  const result: any = {}
  for (const key in mapper) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(mapper, key)) {
      result[key] = (mapper[key] as any)(object[key], key, object)
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

However type TS infers for `out` is `{ foo: any, bar: any }`; it doesn't infer specific types for the properties.

The following produces the correct output type, I'm just not sure if I can parameterize it:

```
const mappers = {
  foo: x => String(x),
  bar: x => parseInt(x),
}
type outputType = {
  [K in keyof typeof mappers]: ReturnType<typeof mappers[K]>
}
// { foo: string, bar: number }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the typing that behaves the best is something like this:

```
function mapShape<T extends { [K in keyof U]?: any }, U>(
    obj: T,
    mapper: { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? (x: T[K]) => U[K] : never }
): U {
    const result: any = {}
    for (const key in mapper) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(mapper, key)) {
            result[key] = (mapper[key] as any)(obj[key], key, obj)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I'm using [inference from mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to allow the output type to be `U` and the `mapper` object to be a homomorphic mapped type on the keys of `U`.

This produces the desired output type for `out` while still inferring the parameter types in the callback properties of the mapper argument:

```
const out = mapShape(
    { foo: 1, bar: '2', baz: 'hello' },
    { foo: x => String(x), bar: x => parseInt(x) }
)
/* const out: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
} */
```

It also should prevent adding properties to the mapper that don't exist in the object to be mapped:

```
const bad = mapShape(
    { a: 1 },
    { a: n => n % 2 === 0, x: n => n } // error!
    // ------------------> ~  ~ <----------
    // (n: any) => any is             implicit any
    // not never
)
```

Okay, hope that helps you proceed; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDKALDBTAHgBVE8APKPMAEwGdEBvRAbQGlEYkBrPATzmCIAqgF0A-AC5EqML0QBfADTCAfAAoAsAChEuxHABGAKylFF2vSgzo8AJylM2HbnwHCRU9uUo16PfoIkYohqZKZsIgCUiAC8KsIRiFJgeABudgrakVJCjBZ6EAi0UIi2eLQgADZQUjJyMYzy+brAcLYhhWDFiP7OVug2ttEMzZYcgmoA8sZ40AB0uLSTAO5gAAq2cINQvHMQqJWVamgDdsr+kcOjY3plFdXM-iKxISeDj3zPqPR1kWqGRg+vBE5z4ygBkWueiaOmhiFGZSgIFsSDuVSg2hh2m0nW6cBAJQaJxw+E0sN0TFacCkAEZlAZUPZEAByABMzPpqAAXlJmdg8Ic4MyFOZyYxEFSpGRYvFMFBbJwAOahSKcpnSuKIdCM2h4ACSYCgKsyWkhWhxRRKDOoL2JuBsZMsTFQtJFo2dyRliCQAFJEKzYjEGgAGZRhb1epDyRAAehjpFsm1sAEJRnHEABaLPZnO57PxAB+uiLBDzObT8bUYFqsmimrqHHoNxuMGQ6EqMAgMBKdQr3rgJRS6VsWSAA)

Comment: huh.  Now when I try to make a `lodash/fp` style version `mapShape(mapper)(obj)`, it doesn't allow `obj` to have extra props.  Not sure if there's any solution for that.

Comment: AFAICT the `T extends { [K in keyof U]?: any }` isn't necessary, or am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, it prevents some compiler errors.  I got an fp version to work, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with @jcalz' answer, I got the following `lodash/fp` style version to work:

```
export default function mapShape<U extends Record<any, (...args: any) => any>>(
  mapper: U
): <T extends { [K in keyof U]?: any }>(
  obj: {
    [K in keyof T]?: K extends keyof U ? Parameters<U[K]>[0] : any
  }
) => { [K in keyof U]: ReturnType<U[K]> } {
  return (obj: any) => {
    const result: any = {}
    for (const key in mapper) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(mapper, key)) {
        result[key] = mapper[key](obj[key], key, obj)
      }
    }
    return result
  }
}

mapShape({
  foo: (x: number) => String(x),
  bar: (x: string) => parseInt(x),
})({
  foo: 1,
  bar: '2',
  baz: 'hello',
})
```